# Azure AppService Slow Connection to SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, azure, performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have an S1 AppService Plan at Azure with a SQL Database connected. I'm using EF Core.
Every now and then, not only after restarts of the app, database commands are extremely slow. The Profiler says only "waiting". But waiting for what?
[Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9r0Q.png)

How can I find out what's blocking here?

Answer (score 0):

It can be observed in the shared Profiler snip that your App has been stuck on `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` method which is taking time to complete and therefore triggering `AWAIT_TIME`, but your parallel threads keep executing. Please visit [double counting in parallel threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-troubleshooting#double-counting) to know more.

The **SaveChangesAsync** method Asynchronously saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database. In order to cancel this process if it is waiting for the task to complete, you need to use `cancellationToken` parameter.

Check the sample code below for your reference:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId="cancellationToken")]
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SaveChangesAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Helpful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_SaveChangesAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to know WHY he is waiting? Connecting to the database? Initialising the DbContext? Trying to migrate the database? Something other? Apparently not querying the database, since this takes 0,5 ms, as we see in the screenshot.

Comment: It is trying to save changes to the database. Might be the changes are more that's why it is taking time. You can go through the documents about this class and methods to know more for better understanding. You don't need to worry about this await time as parallel threads are already running. You can try some code optimization.